# Append to list if not None, within a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary containing some None values under a key, like:

```
tmp = {"frames": ['0', '12', '56', '35', None, '77', '120', '1000']}
```

I need to create a list of elements from the dict, under the "frame" key, which are not `None` (None should be left out). The explicit way is to do:

```
for frame in tmp['frames']:
    if frame:
        output.append(frame)
```

But I was wondering if there's a one-liner expression to do the same. I could think of something like:

```
output = [frame if frame else None for frame in tmp['frames']]
```

but this way, I don't know how to exclude the `None` values

Comment: what do you want to do with the `None`s? remove them? turn them to a value? leave them in?

Comment: They are already integers, you don't need `int()`.

Comment: Sorry, they're stored as strings, fixing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use if condition in list comprehension

```
[int(value) for value in tmp['frames'] if value is not None]
```

Comment: what is the value is the result of a function that I don't want to execute twice ? Can i use lambda ?

Comment: you can use walrus operator